# Let $|G|=p^{(k+l)}q$ with $k, l \geq 0$ and $p \nmid q$. Show that G acts on $X:=\{A \subset G : |A| = p^k \}$ by left multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have the idea of how to prove this for when $|G|=p^kq$, which is as follows.

Let $|G|=p^kq$ such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Let
$$
X=\{A \subset G : |A|=p^k \}.
$$
$G$ acts on $X$ by left translation, that is, $gA:= \{ga : a \in A \}$. $gA$ is an element of $X$ because $a \mapsto ga: A \to G$ is an injection and so $|gA|=|A|$.

But, how do I manipulate this to be shown for when $|G|=p^{(k+l)}q$? Then how do I show that $v_p(|X|)=l?$

Comment: Can I suggest that you do not ask the question in the subject line, or that you at least repeat it in the body of the post? It is much easier to read in the body. The subject lline is supposed to give an indication of what the question is about rather than to contain the question itself.

Comment: You are getting confused by irrelevant details. More generally, if $G$ is any group, and $m$ any cardinal number, and $X = \{ A \subset G : |A| = m \}$, then $G$ acts on $X$ by left multiplication. There is no need to assume that $m$ divides $G$, or even that $G$ or $m$ is finite.